# Light fixture with Pull chain

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

In attempts to open up the light fixture and figure out how to re-attach a chain to the pull chain attachment, the black wire connecting to the pull string fell out of the fixture. I’m not sure if it goes (as you would assume) into the area where the black goes on the fixture, and just want to check for sure. I know the white wire coming from the lamp holder goes into the white spot, so I assume the black on the pull string attachment goes into black. See photos for clarification on my explanation to where I think they should be going.

The second question - do I have to find a part that has both the lamp holder + pull chain mechanism already connected or is it possible to buy just the pull chain? Seems like it may be soldered but wanted to double check.. (see photo 2 of where pull chain mechanism is connected to lamp holder

Thanks in advance!!
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reconnecting the light is just white-to-white and black-to-black.  That's pretty simple, but it never hurts to double check.

As for the second question, it does look like the pull chain switch is riveted to the lamp socket.  Those types of fixtures are cheap these days ($15 for fixture, $5 for just the switch), so you should just replace the whole fixture.  Don't worry about finding a pull chain mechanism and trying to splice the wires, etc.

If you *really* want to keep that fixture because it has sentimental value, you would want to cut the insulated wire going to the pull chain switch as close to the switch as possible to give you plenty of room for a wire splice.  You won't be able to attach directly to the light socket since its riveted, so a wire splice is the only option.

Comment: Thank you! I decided to take your advice and get a new fixture. $10.50 at Home Depot–took 10 min to install.

Comment: @James Great, $15 was what I found on their website, but I figured you could get it for cheaper.  You already did most of the work, so replacement was a no brainer.